# Increasing clarity by breaking verbal stumbling blocks

Tags: ambiguity, sentence-meaning, repetition, complex-sentences, construction

I am marking students' essays and frequently coming across stumbling blocks of words. Although grammatically speaking these blocks are mostly correct, I find that clarity is being impaired (e.g too many adjectives, repetition, word order, confusing meaning, broken flow, too much time spent to understand the message). However, I am not sure how to restructure these stumbling block without loss of meaning so they can understand the point I am trying to make. Can you advise please?

> *I used to have a Giant Live hybrid style brand-new bicicle that was recently stolen from my sister's partner's stepmother.*
>
> *It is an old light blue steel frame road bike with a greyish aluminium handlebar and a cushioned saddle seat.*
>
> *Many cats have disappeared at the same exact time period from the same exact place in the town animal rescue shelter.*
>
> *They research high mortality diseases effects on economically Asian developing nations* OR *They research the effects on economically developing nations in Asia of high mortality diseases.*

Comment: I used to have a bicycle.  It was the Giant brand, hybrid style, and practically brand new.  Unfortunately, it was recently stolen from the stepmother of my sister's partner.

Comment: Had an english teacher who gave an automatic failing grade if she came across a run-on sentence... (That'll learn 'em!)

Comment: Ironically the phrase "stumbling blocks of words" sounds a bit odd to me.

Comment: Thanks @nnnnnn. You're right! I have changed it to "verbal stumbling blocks".

Comment: I would keep no. 1 as part of *writer’s craft*, every writer has their own style of writing and in the literature, that sentence would make me want to read that essay or book. However, I can see the stumbling blocks in no. 2 and 3 - and in no. 4 - it is no question it should be *They research the effects on economically developing nations in Asia of high mortality diseases.*